# How to group <li> in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, html-lists

Say I wanted to do something like

```
const MyElement = (props) => (
    <ul>
        <li>First</li>
        {condition ? <li>Thing 1</li><li>Thing 2</li> : null}
        <li>Second</li>
    </ul>
)
```

Obviously that won't work. I could instead do something like

```
const MyElement = (props) => (
    <ul>
        <li>First</li>
        {condition ? <li>Thing 1</li> : null}
        {condition ? <li>Thing 2</li> : null}
        <li>Second</li>
    </ul>
)
```

or

```
const MyElement = (props) => {
    const thing = <span><li>Thing 1</li><li>Thing 2</li></span>;

    return (
        <ul>
            <li>First</li>
            {condition ? thing.props.children : null}
            <li>Second</li>
        </ul>
    );
}
```

Is there a cleaner or recommended way to do something like this?

Answer (score 3):

You can write it like this also, by using an `array`. Store the ui-items in an `array` and `return` that `array` if the condition is `true`, like this:

```
{1 == 1 ? [<li>Thing 1</li>, <li>Thing 2</li>] : null}
```

I think, The **best way** is to use a `map` and create all the `li` items, like this:

```
let b = [1,2,3].map(el => <li key={el}> {el} </li>)
```

And then `render` it like this:

```
{1 == 1 ? b : null}
```

Check this example:

```js
const MyElement = () => {

    let a = [<li>Thing 1</li>, <li>Thing 2</li>];
    
    let b = [1,2,3].map(el=> <li key={el}> {el} </li>)
    
    return (
       <ul>
           <li>First</li>
        
           {1==1 ? a : null}
           
           {1==1 ? b : null}
        
           {1==1 ? [<li>Thing 1</li>, <li>Thing 2</li>] : null} 
       
           <li>Second</li>
      </ul>
   )
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyElement/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The latter example is generally perfectly fine, but in this case not because `<ul>` cannot have `<span>` children. That's invalid HTML.

The best option would be to return an array, but looks like **Mayank Shukla** already got that covered :) So here are a few other options:

I don't see a a problem your 2nd example. Sure you must evaluate the condition twice but that's fine unless it's a complex condition. If it is complex, you could simplify it slightly:

```js
const Demo = (props) => {
  let myVar = true; //some complex evaluation
  return (
    <ul>
      <li>First</li>
      {myVar ? <li>Thing 1</li> : null}
      {myVar ? <li>Thing 2</li> : null}
      <li>Second</li>
    </ul>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Demo />, document.getElementById('demo'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='demo' />
```

Now you only run your complex condition once and just evaluate a boolean (`myVar`).

---

The other option is to have 2 returns. If the condition is true, the first return executes. Otherwise the last.

```js
const Demo = (props) => {
  if(true) return (
    <ul>
      <li>First</li>
      <li>Thing 1</li>
      <li>Thing 2</li>
      <li>Second</li>
    </ul>
  );
  return (
    <ul>
      <li>First</li>
      <li>Second</li>
    </ul>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Demo />, document.getElementById('demo'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='demo' />
```